# Pass argument from MATLAB to VBA when macro is called

Tags: matlab, vba, interface, arguments

Currently I have a MATLAB script that opens an excel sheet and proceeds to run a macro as code shows:

```html
excelApp = actxserver('Excel.Application');
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Open workbook...
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
excelWB = invoke(excelApp.Workbooks,'Open','O:\Tools\Measurement Database Tool\Parse_Compare_Import.xlsm');
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Run macro...
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
invoke(excelApp, 'Run', 'OpenFiles');
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The important thing is that users of the script will select a folder from which the MATLAB script needs to work, this folder will change for each user so therefore I can not code a folder path into the script, to avoid users having to select the same folder once for MATLAB and again in excel is there a way to pass this pathname from MATLAB to excel when I open and run the macro?

Comment: Is `OpenFiles` an argument for an Excel macro sub?

Comment: That's the macro name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've made a connection to Excel (your `excelApp`), you can put a value from MATLAB (the folder selected by the user) into a particular cell in one of the worksheets in the Excel worksheet.

Then have your Excel macro refer to the value in that cell.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to always use `invoke`, which can gets a bit ugly after a while - you can just use dot syntax. For example, instead of `excelWB = invoke(excelApp, 'Open', 'myFile.xlsx');`, you can write `excelWB = excelApp.Open('myFile.xlsx');`. A lot easier on the eyes. In addition, if you type `excelApp.` and press Tab, you'll get tab-completion with a list of all the available methods and properties of `excelApp`, which makes it much easier to learn/browse the Excel Object Model.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will definitely try this, However I have run into some issues with the matlab to excel interface depending on which PC is used. I now need to "recreate" the MATLAB code in Excel to extract some information, however I am struggling with this as I have very little VBA or matlab experience, if I showed you my code so far do you think you could have a look ?

Comment: If you have another specific question, ask it, and everyone including me will take a look. Alternatively, I'm available for consultancy if you follow the link in my bio... :)